# Keeping the box-shadow when visibility is hidden

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to hide an element but keep it's shadow visible.
For example:

```
// html
<div id="c1" class="cont"></div>
<div id="c2" class="cont"></div>
```

And:

```
// css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

.cont {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  margin: 30px 15px;
  box-shadow: 0px 10px 22px #808aa8;
  background-color: #c2cff2;
}

#c2 {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

([code in JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uxfav68z/7/))

I want `c2` to be hidden (the background shouldn't be visible), but the shadow should be visible.
Right now you can see `c1`.

I can wrap each such div in another container, and hide the inner div while having the shadow on the container, but I was wondering if it's somehow possible without it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could achieve this by abandoning `visibility: hidden;`. If you fade out the background, and remove `pointer-events` from the element, it should give the same effect.

```css
body {
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

.cont {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  margin: 30px 15px;
  box-shadow: 0px 10px 22px #808aa8;
  background-color: #c2cff2;
}

#c2 {
  color: transparent;
  background-color: transparent;
  pointer-events: none;
}
#c2 > * {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="c1" class="cont">
  Hello <img src="#">
</div>
<div id="c2" class="cont">
  Hello <img src="#">
</div>
```

The `pointer-events: none;` style allows the element to be "clicked through" meaning that anything underneath (form elements, buttons etc) can still be interacted with, so depending on your requirements you may not actually need it.

If the elements have content that also need to be faded out, you can set the `color: transparent` on the parent to hide any text and then set any child elements to be hidden with the `#c2 > *` rule.

Comment: The element in question has content in it (image for example), it's not just background, which I chose in the example only to simplify things. Is there a way to do something similar in that case?

Comment: Oh I see! I've updated the answer with a potential solution, but it feels a bit hacky..

Comment: I used that, I'm not loving the hack, but I wasted enough time on this. Thanks

Comment: I know that feeling! Glad I could help, kinda

Answer (score 1):

Use a pseudo-element.

https://jsfiddle.net/9fssfufk/5/

**HTML**

```
<div id="c1" class="cont"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
 html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: red;
}

.cont {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  margin: 30px 15px;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0)
}
.cont:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  box-shadow: 0px 10px 22px blue;

}
```

Comment: This seems like a great solution, but I couldn't make it work on my code. No matter what I did, the `:after` part wasn't visible. My code is way more complex, including positioning, it's unclear what breaks it.

Answer (score 0):

To respond to @Scott Simpson and @Nitzan Tomer, your problem could be that instead of using `:after`, it is more supported to use `::after` (with two colons) on newer browsers.

[Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after#:%7E:text=In%20CSS%2C%20%3A%3Aafter%20creates,It%20is%20inline%20by%20default.)

Comment: How did my answer require clarification from the asker? If you noticed, the OP commented on @Scott Simpson's answer that their solution was great, but that they had some issues with using the `:after` part, so I was addressing that.

Comment: It's been edited twice since then, I compared the version I saw and this one. I wouldn't make the same judgement now.

Answer (score 0):

One cheap way to do it would be to use an `<img>` tag and not set the `src` attribute (yes, you read that right), but only set the `width` and `height` attributes, and give it a `box-shadow`.
And, if you want to put it over something else, set `position: absolute;`, and you can put it where you need it.

Simple Line to Copy:

`<img width="100px" height="100px" style="box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 5px;">`

Example:

```js
var rv = Math.round(Math.random()*255);
var gv = Math.round(Math.random()*255);
var bv = Math.round(Math.random()*255);
```

```css
p {
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 3px white;
}
img {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 5px;
}
```

```html
<body id="bd" style="background-color: whitesmoke;" onclick="
rv=Math.round(Math.random()*100); 
gv=Math.round(Math.random()*100); 
bv=Math.round(Math.random()*100); 
document.getElementById('bd').style.backgroundColor = 'rgb('+rv+', '+gv+', '+bv+')'
"
>
<p>(Click to Change Background Color [to see that it's transparent])</p>
<img width="100px" height="100px"><br>
<p>Over something else:</p>
<p>Words and an image <br>here for you to see <br>the square over something.</p>
<img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1600716051809-e997e11a5d52?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8NXx8c2FtcGxlfGVufDB8fDB8fA%3D%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" width="120px" style="box-shadow: 0px 0px;">
<img width="100px" height="100px" style="position: absolute; top: 224px; left: 36px;"><br>

</body>
```

Or, depending on the element, just set `background-color: transparent` and/or `background-image: none`.

Answer (score 0):

What I do is I move the main Element off the screen with position absolute top: -100px, left: -100px. But the shadow you move the opposite direction:  box-shadow: 500px 800px 1200px 165px #5c63c3;

This way I don't see the ugly empty square of circle, what ever it is, and only the shadow. It's the best I've found and it works great. This is just the shadow element so to speak. Don't put anything inside the main Element of the div, just put this shadow over whatever you wish.